# Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске программа спрашивала дважды у пользователя число на которое нужно делить и текст который нужно выводить?

Tags: c#

мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при запуске программа спрашивала дважды у пользователя число на которое нужно делить и текст который нужно выводить.Далее программа также выводить числа от 1 до 100, но вместо чисел 3 и 5 использует первое и второе заданное число и текст который им соответствует, который ввел пользователь.
Вот сам код:

```
using System;

namespace Numbers5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                var dividesBy3 = i % 3 == 0;
                var dividesBy5 = i % 5 == 0;

                if (dividesBy3 && dividesBy5)
                    Console.WriteLine("OuuMay");
                else if (dividesBy3)
                    Console.WriteLine("Ouu");
                else if (dividesBy5)
                    Console.WriteLine("May");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Проблема в чем именно? Этот код не работает? Как вы это поняли? Как отлаживали? Что вводили в консоль? Кстати, я не вижу нигде ввода чисел. Вы не знаете, как ввести число в консоли? Оригинальный текст задания есть? Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы он стал более понятным и конкретным.

Comment: Код рабочий, мне нужно его исправить так чтобы при запуске программа спрашивала дважды у пользователя число на которое нужно делить и текст который нужно выводить, а потом выводить числа от 1 до 100, но вместо чисел 3 и 5 использует первое и второе заданное число и текст который им соответствует, который ввел пользователь.

Comment: Вы не знаете, как ввести число в консоли? Оригинальный текст задания есть? Или вам просто нужно, чтобы за вас код написали? Скажите, что в ответ то писать.

Comment: я знаю как вывести число в консоль, я также знаю как сделать так чтобы программа спрашивала что то у пользователя. Я не совсем понимаю как сделать так чтобы введенное пользователем число делило числа от 1 до 100 и потом выводить числа от 1 до 100, но вместо чисел 3 и 5 использует первое и второе заданное число и текст который им соответствует, который ввел пользователь. Текст задания я уже скинула.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ввод строки в консоли

```cs
Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
string text = Console.ReadLine();
```

Ввод числа в консоли

```cs
Console.Write("Введите число: ");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Чтобы ввести число и строку, надо сделать так

```
Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
string text = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Введите число: ");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Чтобы сделать это дважды, можно сделать так

```
Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
string text1 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Введите число: ");
int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
string text2 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Введите число: ");
int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Далее подставить все это в код

```cs
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    var dividesBy3 = i % number1 == 0;
    var dividesBy5 = i % number2 == 0;

    if (dividesBy3 && dividesBy5)
        Console.WriteLine(text1 + text2);
    else if (dividesBy3)
        Console.WriteLine(text1);
    else if (dividesBy5)
        Console.WriteLine(text2);
    else
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Начинайте учиться писать код самостоятельно. Чем дальше - тем сложнее будет.

Comment: спасибо, можете что нибудь посоветовать почитать по c#?

Comment: @ВикторияКабишова https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/1.5.php